# How to select first 3 character from array in $row in mysqli_fetch_assoc in while loop?

Tags: php

```
$options_economy = "SELECT * FROM options WHERE question_id='$quest_id'";
$run_opt_economy = mysqli_query($conn, $options_economy);

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_opt_economy)) {
    $options_available = $row2['options'];
}
```

Here is my code. Many options with characters are coming in `$options_available`. I only want to select first 3 characters. How can I do That?

Comment: You can use `LEFT()` in SQL.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 0):

```
$options_available - substr($options_available,0,2);
```

This should limit the string to the first 3 characters

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in PHP using [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) for example:

```php
$options_available = substr($options_available, 0, 3);
```

You can also do this in the database using the [SUBSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) function:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(options, 0, 3) as options FROM options ...
```

or [LEFT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left)

```sql
SELECT LEFT(options, 3) as options FROM options ...
```